# if condition in nginx proxy_pass

Tags: nginx, header

I am trying to route a different upstream based on the version coming from the "customerlocale" header from the client, but the below config is not working. Please give me an idea on how to solve this issue.

```
server {
    listen 80 default;

    location / {

        if ($http_customerlocale = en) {
            proxy_pass http://upstream-en;
        }

        if ($http_customerlocale = de) {
            proxy_pass http://upstream-de;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Assuming you're aware of the implications of `if` **inside** a location block, you might want to consider matching your locale against a case-insensitive regex eg `if ($http_customerlocale ~* "en")`

Comment: @KeenanLawrence, thank you for the reply. I tried this , the "if" condition checking is not working. even tried like this .
set $v "2"
if ( $v = "2" )
        {
        proxy_pass  http://upstream-2;
        }
it not going inside the condition.

Comment: and my nginx version is 1.4.6.

Answer (score 0):

After updating nginx from 1.4.6 to 1.11.3 , it works fine. Thank you.